# Storing data into the database using tableadapater vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

Hey guys I am facing a small problem, I am building a small program in vb.net and access.

I've created a table with an insert query, but when I execute the query from the query builder it works and the data get stored into the database but when I use a code to store, it gets displayed into the `datagridview` but it does not store into the database. Can anyone please help me out ? Thank you in advance for your help.

My code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim productName As String
    Dim producttype As String
    Dim batchno As String
    Dim companyname As String
    Dim expirydate As String
    Dim quantity As Integer
    Dim mrp As Double
    Dim rate As Double
    Dim margin As Double
    Dim totalvalue As Double
    Dim shelfNo As String
    Dim vat As Double
    Dim vatrate As Double
    Dim vat1 As Double
    productName = txtprodname.Text
    producttype = txtprodtype.Text
    batchno = txtbatchno.Text
    companyname = txtcompanyname.Text
    shelfNo = txtshelfno.Text
    expirydate = txtexpdate.Text
    quantity = txtquantity.Text
    mrp = txtmrp.Text

    rate = txtprodrate.Text
    vat1 = txtvat.Text
    vat = (vat1 / 100 * rate)
    vatrate = rate + vat

    margin = mrp - vatrate
    totalvalue = rate * quantity

    Me.ProductTableAdapter.InsertQueryProduct(productName, producttype, batchno, companyname, expirydate, shelfNo, vat, Date.Today, quantity, mrp, rate, margin, totalvalue)
    datagridshow2()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the data to the TableAdapter, but you need to finalize it to the database.

```
Me.Validate()
Me.YourBindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.YourDataSet)
```

Comment: I Did those Changes, but its still not saving the data into the database.

Comment: Do you have a primary key or an autonumber in your table?

Comment: No, I've removed them.

Comment: Without the primary key, the TableAdapter probably does not have enough schema information to determine how to actually Insert a row.  Add in a primary key to the table, fix your dataset, and see if that works.

Comment: Actually, I have several other forms and I did not add any key to some of them ... they still work, the data gets properly inserted into the database. Its just this form. When I use the Execute Button in the query builder and fill the data there, It gets saved into the database. But when i use the table adapter it does not work.